# Getting wrong output with custom linked list implementation

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I am learning list in C++ independently, and i have searched many websites about it. However, almost every approach to create a list is the same.
They usually create a `struct` as the node of a `class`. I want to create a `class` without using `struct`. So I created a class name `ListNode` which contains an `int` data and a pointer.
The main member functions of my class are `AddNode` and `show`.

Although, this program compiles successfully, it still does not work as I wish.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef LISTNODE_H_
#define LISTNODE_H_
#pragma once
class ListNode
{
private:
    int data;
    ListNode * next;

public:
    ListNode();
    ListNode(int value);
    ~ListNode();
    void AddNode(ListNode* node,ListNode* headNode);
    void show(ListNode* headNode);
};

#endif
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#include "ListNode.h"
#include<iostream>


ListNode::ListNode()
{
    data = 0;
    next = NULL;
}

ListNode::ListNode(int value)
{
    data = value;
    next = NULL;
}


ListNode::~ListNode()
{

}    

void ListNode::AddNode(ListNode* node,ListNode* headNode) { 
    node->next = headNode;
    headNode =node;
}

void ListNode::show(ListNode* headNode) {
    ListNode * traversNode;
    traversNode = headNode;
    while (traversNode != NULL) {
        std::cout << traversNode->data << std::endl;
        traversNode = traversNode->next;
    }

}
```

Main function:

```
#include"ListNode.h"
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    ListNode* head = new ListNode();
    for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++) {
        ListNode* Node = new ListNode(i);
        head->AddNode(Node, head);
        }
    head->show(head);
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I am concerned, the output should be

```
2

1

0
```

However, the output is a single zero. There must be something wrong in the `AddNode` and `show` function.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with these two functions?

Comment: If you take out some paper and pencil, and step through your code, one line at a time, you will see the problem. Or, if you're out of paper, you can use your platform's debugger to manually step through the code, and see the values of all variables. This is not a very complicated program. It shouldn't take a long time to debug it.

Comment: I have debugged it, but since i am quiet new to C++ i only know that these two functions are wrong, but i do not know why the AddNode function failed to link nodes in the list.

Comment: If you have really debugged it, then you should be able to answer a simple question: what value you see for head->next after the first call to AddNode() is made, and also after the second call to AddNode().

Comment: Your member functions don't seem good because they don't use class parameters and just doing work with the arguments.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Um.... The value after the first call to AddNode() is a location. There are four parameters including headNode, node, node->next, and this. The value of these are equal.

Comment: Nope. That's not what the debugger would've showed you, had you actually used the debugger. Try again, and this time, _really_ use a debugger.

Comment: @MikeCAT According to the result, i think you are right, but I do not know why the parameters are not operated since i used the pointer.

Comment: I mean parameters of the instance *of which the member functions are called* are not used. You can make these member functions `static` for your implementation, but this is not what you should do. Try to utilize class parameters (member variables).

Comment: @Sam Cheers! I will try again and focus on the change in these parameters' value.

Comment: @MikeCAT I understand and agree with you. But i do not know how to achieve it. I am very sorry to make this kind of request, but could you please tell me the exact code to use member variables? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm guessing that the answer is going to be NO!  I doubt that anyone here will just give you turnkey code, especially when you already broke faith by being economical with the truth about your debugging.

Comment: I mean, look at it from our POV: your posted code may have been simply copied from someone else's homework and you may be trying to get SO to do ALL the work of fixing it for you.  So far, you seem to have made very little effort.

Comment: @Martin James Honestly speaking, i am trying to create my first list program and THIS IS NOT COPIED! You can doubt and criticize my code skill since it is true. The fact is that i have tried this program for three days and searched many websites.

Comment: @MikeCAT I combined@Andrés Guerrero 's code this morning and figured out why my program failed. Though I used pointer when the function is called, I forget the fact that since the value of pointer is location, when the local parameters' value are changed, they cannot match the global pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call head->AddNode(node, head) you´re passing the memory directions which the pointers point, when the function arguments receive those directions, they are now pointing to the same directions, but those are another pointers, no the ones you declared in main. You could see it like this:

```
void ListNode::AddNode(ListNode* node,ListNode* headNode) { 
    /*when the arguments get their value it could be seen as something like:
      node = Node(the one from main) 
      headNode = head(the one from main)*/
    node->next = headNode;
    /*Here you are modifying the new inserted node, no problem*/
    headNode = node;
    /*The problem is here, you´re modifying the memory direction 
      headNode points to, but the headNode argument of the function, no the one declared in main*/
}
```

So the pointer head in main() always points to the same first node you also declared in main().

In order to fix this you should change your code this way:

```
void ListNode::AddNode(ListNode* node,ListNode** headNode) { 
/* second paramater now receives a pointer to apointer to a node */

    node->next = *headNode;//the same as before but due to pointer syntaxis changes a bit
    *headNode = node;//now you change the real head
}
```

And when you call it:

```
head->AddNode(Node, &head);//you use '&' before head
```

Now the real head, no the one in the function, will point to the last node you inserted.